# Function in LISP replacing every non-number in a list/sublist with NIL

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to self-learn LISP programming. I'm having difficulty writing a LISP function that replaces every non-number in a list or sublist with NIL.

For example, if I input (REPLACE '(4 0 4)) it should return (4 0 4).
If I input (REPLACE '(1 2 SHOE (3 4 DOOR))) it should return (1 2 NIL (3 4 NIL))

I'm a bit stuck... how would this be done? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I don't have much, unfortunately, but so far, I have:

```
(defun REPLACE (L)
    (cond ( (NUMBERP L)
```

I know I'd need to check to see if each element in the list is a number using NUMBERP. If anyone could help explain to me how to go from here so I can progress that'd be so helpful.

Comment: You should share your best attempt at a solution. Do you have a partial solution, or an attempt that failed? Also, why `replacenum`? Doesn't the desired function replace _non_-numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the problem up in steps:

**A function that replaces non numbers with nil:**

```
(defun (nil-non-number v)
  ...)

(nil-non-number 3) ; ==> 3
(nil-non-number 'q) ; ==> nil
(nil-non-number "test") ; ==> nil
```

A function that iterates a list and uses `nil-non-number` for each element:

```
(defun replace-non-nums (lst)
  ...)

(replace-non-nums '())                    ; ==> nil 
(replace-non-nums '(4 0 4))               ; ==> (4 0 4)
(replace-non-nums '(4 a 4))               ; ==> (4 nil 4)
(replace-non-nums '(1 2 shoe (3 4 door))) ; ==> (1 2 nil nil)
```

As a last step you need at add a test for `cons` before testing for non numbers and if it is you should also call `replace-non-nums` for that list and use the return there as the element. Then you can test the last one again:

```
(replace-non-nums '(1 2 shoe (3 4 door))) ; ==> (1 2 nil (3 4 nil))
```

All the other tests should yield the same as before as well.